# How do I show the site-wide contact form on a page in Drupal 7?

Tags: forms

I have seen other posts about this, but none specifically for Drupal 7, and I can't get it to work. I am trying to get the default contact form to show up below the main content of a page, perhaps in a block.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You could create a custom block in a module and embed the form there. Something like this (I haven't tested this code!):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 *
 * This hook declares what blocks are provided by the module.
 */
function MODULENAME_block_info() {

  $blocks['contact_block_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Contact Form'),
    );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * This hook generates the contents of the blocks themselves.
 */
function MODULENAME_block_view($delta = '') {
  //The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
  switch ($delta) {
        case 'contact_block_form':
      $block['subject'] = t('Contact Us');
      // Load contact pages inc as the form definition sits there.
          module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I solved this problem by using the module http://drupal.org/project/contact_form_on_node which easily allowed me to add the form to a block.

Thank you Reece Marsland for taking the time to help me out as well!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got a solution.

Comment: You saved my day. Many many thanks to you. Instead of making new module, i played with hook and it worked. But, full credits to you for the hint...